# MS SQL Upsert to mySQL Equivalent

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm moving a msSQL database to mySQL.  In my MS SQL database I have stored procedures that use an "upsert" (update, if @@rowcount = 0, Insert) type of thing.

I want to do the same kind of think in My SQL.  I have found a couple of options

1)  use - Insert xxxx on duplicate key update values (x, y, x) etc.

2)  Replace into table_name (col_name,...) (value,...)

**Which one is more efficient?**  I'm leaning towards the 2nd one since I will be doing a lot of updating, rather than inserting.  Also, I believe that the insert on duplicate key will keep bumping the auto_increment values even when it ends up being an update.

Another note:  Each account record will be updated EVERY night.  Occasionally a new account record will be inserted, but again, primarily the accounts will be updated.

Are there other/better options that I'm overlooking.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: A PS to this - A concern with the Replace is that it does a delete and insert type of Update... not sure if this is any more efficient than insert on duplicate key...

Comment: Maybe you want [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) which handles primary key collisions. It's more annoying to use, but works.

Comment: "I'm moving a msSQL database to mySQL." I might catch some flack from MySQL people but this is a decision that you will forever regret.

Comment: MySQL has it's uses of course, but postgres is a far easier migration target for SQL Server.

Comment: Ha Zane, I hear ya.  I've found MS SQL a bit easier to work with, but it is not my choice.

Comment: `REPLACE` will be trouble if you have foreign keys. They will either obstruct the replace or cascade deletes - which is probably not wanted.

Comment: Looks like ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is the winner.  I've changed some of the SP already, and it seems to work.  It still "feels" like a slower way to do it than the MS SQL upsert, but oh well.  @tadman put in an answer and I'll check mark it.  Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has several facilities for this:

[`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) has the effect of a `DELETE` if the row exists, then `INSERT`. This means it cannot perform partial updates on the data, any fields that are not specified revert to defaults.

[`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) is an option on an `INSERT` that can handle key collisions, including those on a `PRIMARY KEY`. If a duplicate is found, the `UPDATE` statement you specify is executed instead.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO people (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Jeremy')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name)
```

You can use `VALUES()` to specify the same value in the `INSERT` without having to repeat it.

It's important to remember that `NULL` values can be duplicated since they don't exist and aren't equivalent: `NULL=NULL` is false. Non-`NULL` values can be enforced unique, or you can have a `NOT NULL` column to avoid this.